# Javascript equivalent for Ruby's __LINE__ and __FILE__ constants

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-chrome

I primarely code in Ruby but occasionally need javascript for the browser frontend and use the Chrome console to debug the javascript code.

Sometimes it is difficult to follow what code line produces the output, I have to crosscheck at the right end of the line to see the linenumber which is not easy if there is a lot of content, also this linenumber not always corresponds with the line in the sourcefile, there is often an offset when using a template.

In Ruby you have the `__FILE__` constant which contains the sourcecode filepath and the `__LINE__` constant with the linenumber of the code being executed.

So a `p [__LINE__, "what i want to view"]` gives me the linenumber followed by "what i want to view". Is there a javascript/Chrome equivalent ?

For the moment I use

```
console.log(20, "what I want to view")
```

for code on line 20 but you can imagine that has to be changed a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a javascript/Chrome equivalent ?

There is no equivalent I'm afraid. It just doesn't exist. The line numbers you've referred to that are auto-logged by devtools when you use `console.xyz` are the closest you get I'm afraid.

---

> For the moment I use
>
> ```
> console.log(20, "what I want to view")
> ```
>
> for code on line 20 but you can imagine that has to be changed a lot.

FWIW, rather than using a line number that (as you say) needs changing, consider using a marker that doesn't need changing but is easily found, e.g.:

```
console.log("*A*", "what I want to view");
```

That won't need updating so much.

There may well be logging frameworks that do a better job, of course. Or it would be trivial to write a pre-processor for your JavaScript files that replaced `__FILE__`  and `__LINE__` with the name of the file and the line number... (Or perhaps a [Babel plugin](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#toc-stages-of-babel), although `__FILE__` may be tricky; the parsing stage retains line number, but since it may well not even know what file the source is coming from or even if it came from a file [as opposed to output of another tool]...)